# How do I get my Photo Scanner working?

Tags: scanner, epson

I am having trouble getting my **Epson Perfection V100** Photo scanner to run under Ubuntu 12.04.

After I changed my Desktop it seems that I can't install the Epson Scanner.

Does anybody has an idea how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome, have you check if you scanner is support on Ubuntu.  Check here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsScannersEpson

Comment: I seriously doubt that list is complete. Could you run `lsusb` in a Terminal window and post the output here?

Answer (score 1):

I have an Epson V350 Perfection Scanner running on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. I could not get it to work with the latest drivers, but the following worked:

dpkg -i iscan-data_1.8.0-0_all.deb

dpkg -i iscan_2.26.2-1.ltdl7_i386.deb

dpkg -i iscan-plugin-gt-f700_2.1.0-3_i386.deb

These were files I downloaded and saved from a couple of years ago, where iscan is at version 2.26.2-1. The earliest version from avasys (http://avasys.jp/eng/linux_driver/download/) is 2.28 and this did not work for me. Version 2.29 does not install - it complains about missing dependencies libjpeg62 and libltdl3. When I tried to install these, I was told there was "no known source" for libltdl3. Version 2.29 is available from Epson here:
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=20233&DSCCHK=e8c8d6c7f9da68399277d5eddbf8121aecda09d5

Answer (score 0):

There are `.deb` packages of the drivers for the `Epson Perfection V100 scanner` [here](http://www.avasys.jp/lx-bin2/linux_e/scan/DL2.do), which were referenced in an old support ticket at [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/16220). Previously you had to use `alien` to convert the rpms to debs, but now the deb packages are available.

You must install these packages from the first link above in the correct order, by referring to this [guide](http://avasys.jp/eng/linux_driver/faq/id000651.php) and  this more detailed [pdf](http://linux.avasys.jp/drivers/iscan/doc/userg_revP_e.pdf) here. There are **32 bit** and **64 bit** drivers available, so you must choose the right ones for your architecture- this is the 32 bit version given below, but the 64 bit ones will labelled similarly, but with amd64 instead of i386.

Install in the following order:

1) **data package:**  `iscan-data_1.13.0-1_all.deb`

2) **core packages:** (from the Ubuntu 8.10 or later section)`iscan_2.28.1-3.ltdl7_i386.deb` and `iscan-plugin-gt-s600_2.1.2-1_i386.deb`

This is probably your best hope, as your scanner model isn't properly supported in `Sane` or `Xsane` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The current downloads work on ubuntu 12.04 when also installing

http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/hardy/amd64/libltdl3/download

and adding to

```
/etc/udev/libsane-extras.rules
```

the lines:

```
# EPSON Perfection V100
SYSFS{idVendor}=="04b8", SYSFS{idProduct}=="012d", MODE="0664", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are versions of iscan-data and iscan at https://github.com/hean01/iscan and https://github.com/hean01/iscan. I haven't tried these yet, but am putting this here in case someone finds it useful. If I wind up using them I will update.